# React JSS and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jss

I've been using React for a while, and now I want to switch to using React with TypeScript. However, I've grown used to JSS styles (via the `react-jss` package), and I can't understand how I'm supposed to use them with TypeScript. I also use the `classnames` package, to assign multiple class names conditionally, and I get TypeSCript errors for that.

Here is my React component template:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import withStyles from 'react-jss';
import classNames from 'classnames';

const styles = theme => ({
});

class MyClass extends Component {
    render() {
        const { classes, className } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classNames({ [classes.root]: true, [className]: className})}>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default withStyles(styles)(MyClass);
```

I'm just learning TypeScript, so I'm not sure I even understand the errors I get. How would I write something like the above in TypeScript?

**UPDATE**

Here is how I finally converted my template:

```
import React from 'react';
import withStyles, { WithStylesProps }  from 'react-jss';
import classNames from 'classnames';

const styles = (theme: any) => ({
    root: {
    },
});

interface Props extends WithStylesProps<typeof styles> {
    className?: string,
}

interface State {
}

class Header extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    render() {
        const { classes, className } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classNames({ [classes.root as string]: true, [className as string]: className})}>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Header);
```

Things to keep in mind:

- when defining the `styles` object, any member of `classes` that is referenced in the `render` method *has to be defined*. Without TypeScript, you could get away with "using" lots of classes and not defining them, like a placeholder; with TypeScript, they all have got to be there;
- in a call to the `classnames` function, all the keys must be typed. If they come from a variable that *could* be null or undefined, you *have* to add `as string`, or to convert them to string otherwise. Other than this, the `className` property works the same as without TypeScript.

Comment: Could you share an example of the errors you are getting?

Comment: @casieber I don't think they are significative. I couldn't find any reference on React JSS with TypeScript, and tried to "fix" things as I stumbled into them. So most of the errors were probably caused by me trying wrong solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TypeScript, you'll need to define your props as shown in [here](https://cssinjs.org/react-jss/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.16#usage-with-typescript). It is also recommended to use function component if your React component only need `render` method

For your case, the code should look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import withStyles, { WithStyles } from 'react-jss';
import classNames from 'classnames';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {

  }
});

interface IMyClassProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
  className: string;
}

const MyClass: React.FunctionComponent<IMyClassProps> = (props) => {

    const { classes, className } = props;
    return (
        <div className={classNames({ [classes.root]: true, [className]: className})}>
        </div>
    );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(MyClass);
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I'm getting this error on row 2, on "WithStyles": `Module '"<app-path>/node_modules/react-jss/src"' has no exported member 'WithStyles'. Did you mean to use 'import WithStyles from "<app-path>/node_modules/react-jss/src"' instead?`, which seems absurd to me...

Comment: I've found that `WithStyles` is deprecated in favor of `WithStyleProps`. Is this what you meant? https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/blob/17f54cfbe63009838c48fd2a12751302698ef200/packages/react-jss/src/index.d.ts#L44

Comment: Now I'm getting `A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'` when I use my component without specifying a value for `className`. However, I don't always want to specify it - but if I change `IMyClassProps`'s definition to include `className?: string` then I get the error above.

Comment: One last update: I managed to make it compile (pass the type checks) by using `${className}` in backticks. Thank you!